# Is it OK to call pthread_exit from main?

Tags: c, winapi, pthreads, exit, program-entry-point

When I call `pthread_exit` from `main`, the program never gets to terminate. I expected the program to finish, since I was exiting the program's only thread, but it doesn't work. It seems hung.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("-one-\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    printf("-two-\n");
}
```

**Process Explorer** shows that the (only) thread is in `Wait:DelayExecution` state.

According to `pthread_exit` documentation:

> The  process  shall exit with an exit
>   status of 0 after the last thread has
>   been terminated. The behavior shall be
>   as  if  the  implementation called
>   exit() with a zero argument at thread
>   termination time.

I'm using **Dev-C++ v4.9.9.2** and **pthreads-win32 v2.8.0.0** (linking against `libpthreadGC2.a`).

The library seems to be OK (for example, calling `pthread_self` or `pthread_create` from `main` works fine).

Is there any reason for what I'm not supposed to call `pthread_exit` from `main`?

Comment: Why don't you `return 0;` instead of `pthread_exit(NULL);`?

Comment: I know I _could_ `return` or `exit`. I just want to know if it's legal to terminate the main thread by calling `pthread_exit`.

Comment: Returning from main() is very different to running pthread_exit().  The latter will let the rest of alive threads to finish and then exit with return value 0.
The former will terminate everything immediately.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well its definately legal in the linux implementation of pthreads, see the notes section in [pthreads_exit](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html). It states

> To allow other threads to continue execution, the main thread should terminate
>   by calling pthread_exit() rather than exit(3).

Further, a look at the source code [here](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/pthreads/pthread_exit.c?rev=1.9&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&cvsroot=pthreads-win32) (torwads the end) shows that it roughly translates to _endthread or _endthreadex. The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73(VS.80).aspx) for those makes no mention of not calling it in the initial thread.

Comment: Then I guess it should be legal in the win32 implementation (http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/bugs.html) too. I've been looking for a known bug that explains this behavior, but I couldn't find it.

In my opinion, either this is a buggy behavior or there's an actual reason I am not supposed to call `pthread_exit` on `pthreads_win32`. Can anybody confirm any of these hypothesis?

Comment: @matasierra: I've added some more detail to the answer aboce. Also, what is main actually executing?

Comment: The first `printf` is actually printed out, but the second one is not (as expected). The problem is that the program will not terminate. It simply gets kind of _frozen_.

Comment: I finally found the problem. I think it was some kind of malware on my operating system. I've just cleaned it up with an antispyware tool and now it works as expected. Oh, my... I feel really stupid.

@torak I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19):

This completely legal and intended behavior. The whole process only ends when either all threads terminate or `exit` is called explicitly or implicitly.

A normal return from `main` is equivalent to a call to `exit`. If you end `main` with `pthread_exit` your are saying explicitly that you want the other threads to continue.

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to use pthread_exit in main. When pthread_exit is used, the main thread will stop executing and will remain in zombie(defunct) status until all other threads exit.

If you are using pthread_exit in main thread, cannot get return status of other threads and cannot do clean-up for other threads (could be done using pthread_join(3)). Also, it's better to detach threads(pthread_detach(3)) so that thread resources are automatically released on thread termination. The shared resources will not be released until all threads exit.

Its ok to use when not allocating resources in the main thread, clean-up is not needed. Below code shows using pthread_exit in the main thread. The second printf in main is not printed as main thread exits after calling pthread_exit. Ps output shows the defunct main thread.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *functionC(void *);

int main()
{
        int rc;
        pthread_t th;

        if(rc = pthread_create(&th, NULL, &functionC, NULL))
        {
                printf("Thread creation failed, return code %d, errno %d", rc,                 errno);
        }

        printf("Main thread %lu: Sleeping for 20 seconds\n", pthread_self());
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(20);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        printf("Main thread %lu: This will not be printed as we already called         pthread_exit\n", pthread_self());
        exit(0);
}

void *functionC(void *)
{
        printf("Thread %lu: Sleeping for 20 second\n", pthread_self());
        sleep(20);
        printf("Thread %lu: Came out of first and sleeping again\n", pthread_self());
        sleep(20);
        printf("CThread %lu: Came out of second sleep\n", pthread_self());
}
```

Output of the above code:

```
Main thread 140166909204288: Sleeping for 20 seconds
Thread 140166900684544: Sleeping for 20 second
Thread 140166900684544: Came out of first and sleeping again
CThread 140166900684544: Came out of second sleep
```

`ps` output:

```
root@xxxx-VirtualBox:~/pthread_tst# ps -elfT |grep a.out
0 S root      9530  9530  9496  0  80   0 -  3722 hrtime 17:31 pts/1    00:00:00 ./a.out
1 S root      9530  9531  9496  0  80   0 -  3722 hrtime 17:31 pts/1    00:00:00 ./a.out
0 S root      9537  9537  2182  0  80   0 -  5384 pipe_w 17:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto a.out

root@xxxx-VirtualBox:~/pthread_tst# ps -elfT |grep a.out
0 Z root      9530  9530  9496  0  80   0 -     0 -      17:31 pts/1    00:00:00 [a.out] <defunct>
1 S root      9530  9531  9496  0  80   0 -  4258 hrtime 17:31 pts/1    00:00:00 ./a.out
0 S root      9539  9539  2182  0  80   0 -  5384 pipe_w 17:31 pts/0    00:00:00 grep     --color=auto a.out`
```

Please check blog [Tech Easy](http://techeasyblogs.blogspot.com/) for more information on threads.

Answer (score 1):

When testing on Linux (CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)) I found that indeed the main program waits for "child" threads to continue.
Also I was not able to pass out a return code from main, although it can be specified as argument for pthread_exit(), as Raul said above it always returns with exit code 0:

```
retval=3;
pthread_exit(&retval);
```

We also observed an error message when using Clang compiler (version 3.4.2) and sanitizer options:

```
==5811==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x7f4c090321d0 in thread T0
#0 0x7f4c08be3e29 in __interceptor_free (/home/karstenburger/tests/libc/pthread_exit_in_main/a+0x65e29)
#1 0x7f4c08333358 in free_key_mem (/lib64/libdl.so.2+0x1358)
#2 0x7f4c08745bc1 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd (/lib64/libpthread.so.0+0x7bc1)
#3 0x7f4c07771b38 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x21b38)
#4 0x7f4c08bfa08c in _start (/home/karstenburger/tests/libc/pthread_exit_in_main/a+0x7c08c)

AddressSanitizer can not describe address in more detail (wild memory access suspected).
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free ??:0 __interceptor_free
==5811==ABORTING
```

Comment: Did you use a local variable for `retval`, so its address becomes invalid?