# Terminating the program gracefully in C

Tags: c, exit, termination

I have sort of a homework and it asks me to end the program gracefully without explicit termination such as calling exit() or killing the threads.
However I cannot think of any other methods than `return 0`, so what are the methods to end a program gracefully?

Comment: `main` will by default return *0* in the lack of a `return 0;` statement.

Comment: Gracefully ? Perhaps they meant printing "Goodbye" ?

Comment: "Thou shalt permit the programme to dye..."

Comment: @Cnicutar, I don't think so as it does not allow us to use exit()

Comment: Can you post the text of the homework ? Maybe you're not reading it completely right :-)

Comment: @cnicutar
"The
input 'q' indicates that the simulation has terminated. Note that the simulation must end
gracefully without explicit termination such as calling exit() or killing the threads."

Comment: I believe what your homework says is that you should not have more than 1 exit point. Be it a `return 0`, or an `exit(0)`, it should not make any difference.

Comment: How about if I use return EXIT_SUCCESS; ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Killing the threads is absolutely not a graceful way to terminate a program. I think what your instructor means is that all your `parent` threads should wait on their `child` threads before terminating themselves.

Ideally, an explicit call `pthread_exit` from the main thread would ensure that all it's children continue running even after it exits. Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559463/is-it-ok-to-call-pthread-exit-from-main). But, the safest way to wait on your child threads before exiting is to use `pthread_join`.

Nevertheless, `exit(0)` is the graceful return for a process as such.

Comment: This is correct answer, when I asked to my teacher, what needs to be done was actually `pthread_join` waits the thread to return NULL with `pthread(threadname, NULL);` so in my threads there were loops inside of them, so the solution was to finish these loops with a variable so that all threads could return NULL

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to tell us that you have a multi-threaded program. I suppose that the the idea of gracefully terminating the program is meant to terminate all your threads by setting a flag or something like that. And then only to terminate your `main` after all your threads have provably ended. The way you actually then terminate your `main` is of lesser importance.

Comment: +1. It's not about language syntax nor methods of terminating a process. It's about properly ending threads, closing and deallocating resources, etc. That's what I understand from *gracefully*.

Answer (score 0):

`exit(0)` generally indicates that process (your program) terminated gracefully. In case of error it would `exit(-1)` or some other error code.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what they could mean with gracefully but my first idea was just a return 0.

Or exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340388/terminating-the-program-gracefully-in-c#comment16566776_12340388).

> `main` will by default return *0* in the lack of a `return 0;` statement.

See §5.1.2.2.3¶1 of the C99 standard.

> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
>   initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of `0`. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

So, the following terminates gracefully although implicitly, distinguished from an explicit `exit` or `return` in `main`.

```
main() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

They may be referring to how you handle errors in lower-level routines. Rather than doing something like

```
printf("ERROR: couldn't initialize the claveman\n");
exit(1);
```

You would return from that routine (possibly printing the error message at that level or waiting to do it at a higher level like main()).

```
return CLAVEMAN_INITIALIZE_ERROR;
```

All your routines would return zero for success or non-zero error codes, up until the code in main was able to return either EXIT_SUCCESS or an error code indicating the failure.