# Is it possible to get a thread object for the main thread, and `join()` with it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Is there a way to treat the main thread like any other thread with the C++11 (or later) facilities?
Concretely, I am looking for is the ability to `join()` with the main thread. So, basically, I would like to do something like: `main_thread.join()`, but don't know how to obtain the `main_thread` object.

The thread constructors do not seem to offer any facilities based for instance on the thread id obtained with `get_id()`. The `this_thread` namespace offers also only minimal functionality, but misses for instance `join()`, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Usually you start a thread from the main thread and then join() the thread you started.. not the other way around.

Comment: [std::thread::join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) method is there for c++11.Whats problem?

Comment: Er...if you want to join the main thread, what exactly is the difference to just ending the current thread? It's not like you're ever going to continue; the program is over when the main thread ends.

Comment: I need the ability to do `main_thread.join()`. In my case, the main thread is just like any other thread, not specially at all. Each thread is running arbitrary user code, which needs to be able to call `join()`.

Comment: When `main` exits, all other threads are destroyed. The main thread is by definition *not* "just like any other thread".

Comment: You *could* spawn your own "main thread" which *is* just like any other thread and join that, of course.

Comment: NO. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/c11-what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo, wasn't aware that main mandates to stop execution of all threads. Ok, I guess, that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @molbdnilo You can end the main thread without terminating all the others ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559463/is-it-ok-to-call-pthread-exit-from-main))

Comment: @ElderBug ok, well, I guess that's outside the C++11 language, and since I do not say any equivalent for `thread`, it looks like I'll have to work around it in another way.

Comment: Who closevoted this as requiring a testcase? Silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @molbdnilo and @yohjb (see also [What happens to a detached thread when main() exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744250/c11-what-happens-to-a-detached-thread-when-main-exits)), C++11 semantics say that all threads are ended when the `main()` function terminates.
Since C++11 does not have a `pthread_exit()` equivalent, the main thread cannot be joined, because the program would end anyway.

So, to answer my question, it does not seem to be possible, and with the terminating semantics of `main()`, it would not be very useful.

Comment: FYI this didn't need to be community wiki! It's a perfectly reasonable question and answer.