# When is a process in UNIX terminated?

Tags: unix, process, fork

I am confused about the ending of a process in UNIX. When is a process in UNIX terminated? Should we necessarily write `exit(0)`  to terminate a process? In my view- no, but I cannot figure out the difference between those two pieces of code.

```c
pid_t pid=fork();
if(pid < 0)
{
             perror("Fork error\n");
             return 1;  
}
else if (pid==0) /* child */
{
             //Do some operations here
}
else
{
            wait(NULL);
            //Do some operations
}
```

and

```c
pid_t pid=fork();
if(pid < 0)
{
                 perror("Fork error\n");
                 return 1;  
 }
 else if (pid==0) /* child */
 {
                 //Do some operations here
                 exit(0);
 }
 else
 {
                wait(NULL);
                //Do some operations here
 }
```

Probably we need the `exit(0)` only for the `wait()` function. In this case, what would happen if we make `wait()` without having done `exit(0)`
 before?

Comment: When the main routine returns then exit will be called.

Comment: Should I use exit everythime I want to exit a process?
What is the difference if I use or if I do not use exit ?

Comment: You must use exit if not in `main`. Return is equivalent in main so it is up to you.

Comment: But I still don't understand is it possible to terminate the process without calling exit.
Also what is the difference between the 2 examples that I described in the question?

Comment: If that is main, then there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### POSIX

See [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html):

> **Terminating a Process**
>
> It is important that the consequences of process termination as described occur regardless of whether the process called `_exit()` (perhaps indirectly through `exit()`) or instead was terminated due to a signal or for some other reason.
>
> `[...]`
>
> As required by the ISO C standard, using return from `main()` has the same behavior (other than with respect to language scope issues) as calling `exit()` with the returned value. Reaching the end of the `main()` function has the same behavior as calling `exit(0)`.

See also [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html). Normal termination:

> If `wait()` or `waitpid()` return because the status of a child process is available, these functions shall return a value equal to the process ID of the child process. `[...]` The value stored at the location pointed to by `stat_loc` shall be `0` if and only if the status returned is from a terminated child process that terminated by one of the following means:
>
> - The process returned `0` from `main()`.
> - The process called `_exit()` or `exit()` with a status argument of `0`.
> - The process was terminated because the last thread in the process terminated.

List of specified termination reasons:

> - `WIFEXITED(stat_val)`
>
>   Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that terminated normally.
> - `WIFSIGNALED(stat_val)`
>
>   Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that terminated due to the receipt of a signal that was not caught (see `<signal.h>`).

and respective status information:

> - `WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)`
>
>   If the value of `WIFEXITED(stat_val)` is non-zero, this macro evaluates to the low-order 8 bits of the status argument that the child process passed to `_exit()` or `exit()`, or the value the child process returned from `main()`.
> - `WTERMSIG(stat_val)`
>
>   If the value of `WIFSIGNALED(stat_val)` is non-zero, this macro evaluates to the number of the signal that caused the termination of the child process.

---

### Summary

To sum up, POSIX mentions two ways how a process can be terminated:

- process can terminate itself, if it calls `exit()`, `_exit()` or returns from `main()` or last thread of the process terminates;
- process can be killed by signal (sent by kernel, or some another process, or the process itself).

---

### Threads

See also ["Is it OK to call pthread_exit from main?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559463/is-it-ok-to-call-pthread-exit-from-main) if you need to prevent all threads to terminate when `main()` returns.

---

### Using `exit()` in child

> In this case, what would happen if we make `wait()` without having done `exit(0)` before?

`fork()` duplicates current process and both parent and child continue execution from the same point when `fork()` returns.

Consider the following example:

```cpp
int main() {
    if (fork() == 0) { /* child */
        foo();
    }
    else { /* parent */
        wait(NULL);
    }

    bar(); /* called in parent in child */
    return 0; /* or exit(0) */
}
```

In this example, child does not call `exit()` in its `if` branch, so after calling `foo()` it calls `bar()` and than returns from `main()` causing child process termination. In other words, both child and parent call `bar()` here.

Usually it's not what you want and you write this instead:

```cpp
int main() {
    if (fork() == 0) { /* child */
        foo();
        exit(0);
    }
    else { /* parent */
        wait(NULL);
    }

    bar(); /* called only in parent */
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, child exits immediately after calling `foo()` so that `bar()` in not called in child.