# How do I call a function that returns a void pointer?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I have this piece of code shown below.

Where *nrthr* stands for number of threads and is entered by the user. I always want my "main program" to call testFunc once, so if the user enter nrthr to be number 3 I then want to create 2 new threads. So my question is... how can I just call testFunc before the while loop?

```
int threadCount = 0;
...

// Call testFunc here

while(threadCount < nrthr - 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Created thread: %d\n", threadCount);
        if(pthread_create(&(tid[threadCount++]), NULL, testFunc, args) != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't create thread\n");
}

void *testFunc(void *arg)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with something like `void* pin, *pout; pout = testFunc(pin);` ?

Comment: what prevents you from calling it as a normal function void *ret = testFunc(somedata/NULL)?

Comment: I guess that's how I should do it, I just thought I could call it without creating a variable since the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Fjodor, sure, if you don't care about the return value, you don't need to store it in a variable, and you can just call your function: `testFunc(NULL)`, or whatever value you want to pass to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `testFunc` is supposed to run on a separate thread, then it *may* be the case that it doesn't simply do something and return.

If that assumption is true, you can't simply call it before your loop, otherwise your main thread won't reach the point of creating the other threads to run **simultaneously**.

If that assumption is false, then you can simply call it like any other function, `testFunc(args)`, and ignore the return value if you don't care about it. Another thing to note is the behaviour of `pthread_exit` when it's called from the main thread - See [Is it OK to call pthread_exit from main?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559463/298054).

Answer (score 2):

You can call `testFunc` like this:

```
void *result = testFunc(args);
```

Beware, however, if `testFunc` calls any pthread related functions.  Since in this case the function is not running in a separate thread, calling functions like `pthread_exit` will not work as you might expect.