# Multi threading using p thread Linux problem

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, nidaqmx

I have two functions, producer and consumer called by two p threads, but the while loop in the function is not running. Its a linux RT system. this is my code. im coding in eclipse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include"NIDAQmx.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include "sts_queue/s_q.c"
#include <stdlib.h>

void *producer(void *ptr);// first function
void *consumer(void *ptr);// second function

TaskHandle taskHandle = 0;
int ret = 0;
int numChannels = 0;
int numRead;
float64 data[100];
int iret1, iret2;
pthread_t thread1, thread2;

int main(void) {
char *message1 = "Producer ended";
char *message2 = "consumer ended";
    init();
ret = DAQmxCreateTask("task", &taskHandle);

ret=DAQmxCreateAIVoltageChan(taskHandle, "PXI1Slot2/ai0", "",
        DAQmx_Val_Cfg_Default, -5, 5, DAQmx_Val_Volts, NULL);

ret=DAQmxCfgSampClkTiming(taskHandle, "", 1000, DAQmx_Val_Rising,DAQmx_Val_ContSamps, 100);

ret=DAQmxGetTaskAttribute(taskHandle, DAQmx_Task_NumChans, &numChannels);


ret=DAQmxStartTask(taskHandle);

iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, producer,(void*) message1);// calling two threads
iret2 = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, consumer,(void*) message2);// calling thread



}

void *producer(void *ptr) // enque function
{
char *message;
int i = 0;
int ret;
message = (char *) ptr;
while(i<1000)
{
//ret=DAQmxReadAnalogF64(taskHandle, 100, 10.0, DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel, data,100 * numChannels, &numRead, NULL);
printf("task handle=%d\n",taskHandle);
printf("value of i=%d\n",i);
printf("Number of sample read%d\n",numRead);
printf("ret%d\n",ret);
sleep(.1);
i++;
}
ret=DAQmxStopTask(taskHandle);

ret=DAQmxClearTask(taskHandle);

printf("%s \n", message);
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
return 0;
}

void *consumer(void *ptr) // deque function
{
char *message;
int k = 0;
int elements=0;
message = (char *) ptr;
while(k<1000)
{

    printf("value ofk=%d\n",k);
    sleep(.1);
    k++;
}
printf("%s \n", message);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

 }
```

Should i use pthread_exit or pthread-join?
how to use pthead_exit to exit first thread when while loop has exited?

now my console prints just this

```
task handle=-163491360
start0
value ofk=0
task handle=-163491360
value of i=0
Number of sample read0
ret0
logout
```

but actually value of i and k should go to 1000 and when it reaches 1000, while loop will stop and exit

Sometimes im getting this error too

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
logout
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pthread_join` in the `main` function after creating thread1 and thread2. Otherwise, the main thread will terminate before thread1 and thread2 are completed.

Comment: should i use pthread_join  or pthread_exit? for exiting this thread?
and should my void main() have a while loop ,to keep it active till my thread exit?

Comment: You have to call `pthread_join` from the `main` function in order to wait for the other threads to complete. A while loop in `main` is not required, as `pthread_join` makes sure the main thread is kept active until the others complete.

Comment: If you call `pthread_exit` at the end of main, the main thread (and your program) will continue to run in the background until all other threads complete but you will not see the ouput. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3559873/4865273

Comment: Allocated resources will be freed when `pthread_join` returns because it means the threads have been destroyed.

Comment: @tomptz no, resources such as dynamically allocated memory will NOT be destroyed upon thread exit unless that thread is the last one in the process, (and then the OS blows everything away that is not shared with another process).

Comment: Indeed, but in this case, the return from the calls to `pthread_join` will be directly followed by the main process exiting anyway